# Can you use php on a Eclipse Java EE dynamic web project?

Tags: php, eclipse, filenames

I am trying to include php onto my dynamic web developing project on eclipse. When I put php onto a page I get a blank page. Is there a particular plugin that would work easily with the version of eclipse I have now. I am trying to use PHP to open a folder and read the file names in the folder. I've read this is best done with php? I could be wrong. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.eclipse.org/pdt (the very first link when you type "php" and "eclipse" into a Google search).  You can add it as a plugin to an existing Eclipse install... or for that matter, just download the specialized Eclipse build for PHP developers on the main Eclipse download site.

Of course, while this does answer your specific question... you should probably provide more context and ask broader questions.  What you are asking makes little sense.  Are you trying to mix PHP with Java code?  Or are you completely new to web development altogether, just happened to pick Eclipse for an IDE, and aren't sure where to start or which language to use?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing different server-side languages is generally a very bad idea. And getting the file names inside a folder is not difficult at all in Java:

```
String[] fileNames = new File(folderName).list();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am really new to web developing, how would I include Java into the project?

Comment: @corazondeluna04: If you have a Java EE dynamic web project, you don't have to "include Java", it's already a Java project.

Comment: I know that but is there a certain way I'm supposed to link it up to a javascript file

Comment: Are you trying to list files on the client side? That's a completely different question and has nothing to do with PHP or Java EE.

Comment: I am trying to pull the filenames from an images folder where the webcontent of the project lives. I'm not very familiar with eclipse and any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @corazondeluna04: then what do you mean with "link it up to a javascript file"? Anything that happend on the server is NOT implemented in Javascript. Or are you confusing Java and Javascript? Overall it sounds like you're lacking the most basic understanding how web programming works and trying to do too much too fast. You should probably start out with some very basic tutorials.